# How to insert a syllable before a single vowel

Tags: java, char, stringbuilder

I try to insert a syllable before each vowel with the following restrictions:

**- Before each** following vowel **(a, e, i, o, u)**, **insert** the stray syllable **"av"**.

**- Unless the vowel is preceded by another vowel**

Actually I've done this

```
public static String translate(String text) {
    char [] charArray = text.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(char c : charArray) {
        if (charArray.length < 255){
            if (isVowel(c)) {
                sb.append(String.format("av%s" , c));
            }
            else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a') || (c == 'e') ||
            (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') ||
            (c == 'u');
}
```

With words without double vowels it works perfectly:

Cat becomes

```
Cavat
```

But with double vowel it doesn't work

Meet becomes

```
Maveavet // Should return Meet
```

How to check if 2 successive letters are vowels in order not to add the syllable if it's the case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to consider a following (or preceding) element of an array you should either store it somewhere or (easier) use a classic `for` loop instead of an enhanced one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that uses an ordinary for loop:

```
public static String translate(String text) {
    char [] charArray = text.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u'));

    char cFirst = charArray[0];
    if (vowels.contains(cFirst) && !(vowels.contains(charArray[1]))) {
        sb.append(String.format("av%s" , cFirst));
    }
    else sb.append(cFirst);

    for (int i = 1; i < charArray.length-1; i++){
        char c = charArray[i];
        char cNext = charArray[i+1];
        char cPrev = charArray[i-1];

        if (vowels.contains(c) && !(vowels.contains(cNext) || vowels.contains(cPrev))) {
            sb.append(String.format("av%s" , c));
        }
        else sb.append(c);
    }

    char cLast = charArray[charArray.length-1];
    if (vowels.contains(cLast) && !(vowels.contains(charArray[charArray.length-2]))) {
        sb.append(String.format("av%s" , cLast));
    }
    else sb.append(cLast);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Works for all the cases I could think of, but probably not the optimal way of doing this.

Comment: @Seth consider accepting the answer in that case :)

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to manage the indexes yourself instead of using an enhanced for loop. This allows you to 'skip' over two vowel chunks by checking the next character if it exists. Something like this should work:

```java
    int i = 0;
    while (i < charArray.length) {
        char c = charArray[i];
        if (isVowel(c)) {
            if (i + i == charArray.length || isVowel(charArray[i+1])) {
                sb.append("av");
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        sb.append(c);
        i++;
    }
```

Note that this does not solve for when there are three sequential vowels.

Comment: With that method it doesn't work for single & double vowel